# Pattern WaitAllOneByOne with semaphoreSlim, is this implementation thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I have two tasks to perform, one gets data and takes about 2 seconds to complete and the other one processes the data and takes about 3 seconds. I have to run this two tasks for about 13.000 different elements. If I run this tasks secuentially, it will take about 18 hours to complete.

Now I was thinking in using the pattern WaitAllOneByOne , but calling `Task.Run` on every element will collapse my database so I thought of implementing a SemaphoreSlim to control how many threads should run on each task.

So far I was able to create an implementation of the pattern but **I don't know if it is thread safe and I'm out of ideas on how to test it**.

The code is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Guid> idsCombinacion = GetIdsCombinacion(10);
        List<Task<string>> todo = new List<Task<string>>(idsCombinacion.Count);
        List<Task> processing = new List<Task>(idsCombinacion.Count);

        //this starts callings to GetData, up to 2 threads.
        SemaphoreSlim semaphoreGetData = new SemaphoreSlim(2);
        var dataTask = GetDataAsync(idsCombinacion, todo, semaphoreGetData);

        SemaphoreSlim semaphoreProcessData = new SemaphoreSlim(3);
        while (todo.Count > 0)
        {
            Task<string>[] tasks = todo.ToArray();
            int idx = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
            todo.RemoveAt(idx);

            //once the tasks in the to-do list goes finishing, we start a new task to perform the Processing, up to 3 threads
            semaphoreProcessData.Wait();
            var result = tasks[idx].Result;
            tasks[idx].Dispose();
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine($"todo: {todo.Count}; processing: {processing.Count}; guid: {result}");
                semaphoreProcessData.Release();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            processing.Add(t);

        }

        var aux = processing.ToArray();
        //we wait for all the jobs to complete
        Task.WaitAll(aux);

        await dataTask;

        semaphoreGetData.Dispose();
        semaphoreProcessData.Dispose();
    }

    private static async Task GetDataAsync(List<Guid> idsCombinacion, List<Task<string>> todo, SemaphoreSlim semaphoreGetData)
    {
        foreach (var idComb in idsCombinacion)
        {
            await semaphoreGetData.WaitAsync();
            var t = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
                semaphoreGetData.Release();
                return "Guid: " + idComb;
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            todo.Add(t);
        }
    }


    private static List<Guid> GetIdsCombinacion(int howMany)
    {
        var idsCombinacion = new List<Guid>(howMany);
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            idsCombinacion.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        return idsCombinacion;
    }
}
```

The pattern WaitAllOneByOne by Dr. Joe Hummel in this [pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/intro-async-parallel-dotnet4).
[image]

Comment: It is throwing an object disposed exception at `Task.WaitAll(aux);` because you are trying to wait for a job to complete for which semaphore is already disposed of.

Comment: sorry @KeyurRamoliya, check now. This happens because I didn't check if it worked in the latest versions (yes, I added the usings there)

Comment: BTW, I would love to use `.ContinueWith`, but I can't figure out how I could control threading differently and how that would be different from a `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: I think you should go with `Parallel.ForEach` in which you can start new `Thread` for each task and it will block that until it is finished so you don't need to explicitly verify that it is thread-safe or not.

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya, this is a critical process for the organization, it already uses `Parallel.ForEach`, I'm looking for an even better aproach. Also, I'm using this little project to increase my learning on Threading and Task-Parallel-Library